# Want to print alphabets next to the input provided in java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I am trying to print the next upcoming alphabets from the input provided but when I am trying it is giving me an error message `"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to char at Charactertest.test.main(test.java:18)"`

Below is the code:-

```
package Charactertest;
import java.util.Scanner;


class chartest
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    char alpha= s.next().charAt(0);
}

public class test {
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter an alphabet:-");
        chartest c = new chartest();
        for(char d=c.alpha+1;d<='y';d++)
        {
            System.out.println("And the next character is: " +c.alpha);
            c.alpha++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `s` in `char alpha= s.next().charAt(0);`?

Comment: Sorry missed one statement in copying..editing the post.

Comment: @Michael :- Can u please take a look now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of your first class. BTW, you should capitalize the names of your classes and follow the [camelCase or under_score](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27264/naming-conventions-camelcase-versus-underscore-case-what-are-your-thoughts-ab) naming convection for identifiers' names.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a letter:");
        char c = in.next().charAt(0); //there's no in.nextChar :(
        c++; //start out one character ahead
        for(; c <='y'; c++){
            System.out.println("And the next character is: " + c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok but the problem is still there. If i provide input as 'a' then system is also printing letter a and i want it to print from the next letter i.e. 'b'. Can u help me in that? Beacuse i was able to print the same result by just removing +1  from the for loop in my code as well.

Comment: increment `c` by one before you enter the loop, like my code does @GauravSharma

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
for(char d=c.alpha+1;d<='y';d++)
```

`c.alpha + 1` returns and `int`. You're trying to assign it to a `char`.

What you could do is `char d = (char)(c.alpha + 1)`

Comment: Yes i know sir.. the problem is i want my code to work like if i am giving the input as 'a' then it should print the remaining letters starting from 'b'. So i was trying to start my loop from the next letter thats why i i used char d=c.alpha+1 in for loop. but apparently as u said it cannot be asigned to char so i am blocked here. can u tell me the right way to do it.

Comment: Well I did suggest the `char d = (char) (c.alpha + 1)` change. The structure of the code in general is a bit odd, try to learn from Michael's proposed solution.

Comment: Ohh..really sorry i missed that..Yes i am learning fro, the technocrats like u :)!!